# Open front facing camera with HTML input type "File"

Tags: html, mobile, browser, device

I am facing problem with HTML code, which when opened in the mobile web browser has one input type file that opens the mobile back camera, i need to force open front facing camera. My code is as below. I know user can switch camera mode when camera is opened but i want to open by default front facing camera. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" capture="user" />
   <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried your code above mentioned.
It was working for me when I opened from mobile browsers.
But I think it won't work on desktop.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/capturing-images

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="user">
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="environment">
```

Adding the capture attribute without a value let's the browser decide which camera to use, while the "user" and "environment" values tell the browser to prefer the front and rear cameras, respectively.

The capture attribute works on Android and iOS, but is ignored on desktop.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).